# How to add Firebase-Crashlytics to Flutter project?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, crashlytics

Trying to add Firebase Crashlytics to an app. Added to file android/app/build.gradle: apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'. Added to the android/build.gradle file: classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'.
Initialized:

```js
if (!kIsWeb) {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance
        .setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
  }
  FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
}
```

In my initState created a crash():

```js
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash();
}
```

But nothing is output in the console: [image]

How to set it up correctly?

Comment: https://github.com/praveengupta0895/analytics_crashlytics, please refer this.

Comment: For this first remove the 'if(kDebugMode)' condition if you are directly testing by installing from your IDE

Answer (score 1):

1. Install **firebase_crashlytics** `flutter pub add firebase_crashlytics`
2. Inside `android/build.gradle` inside `dependencies` include `classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'`
3. Inside `android/app/build.gradle` at the bottom after `dependencies {}` include `apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'`
4. Then navigate to your `main.dart` and inside your `void main(){}` include  `await Firebase.initializeApp();` and `FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;`
5. Official Documentation of Firebase Crashlytics
   https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/usage

Answer (score 0):

If this line is getting executed, then Crashlytics won't send any crashes:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
```

See this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=flutter#enable-reporting) for reference. Make sure this is not getting executed when running your tests.

Also, when testing, I would recommend you having more control when the crash happens, like using a button. Similar to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=flutter#force-test-crash):

```
TextButton(
    onPressed: () => throw Exception(),
    child: const Text("Throw Test Exception"),
),
```

The Crashlytics SDK, in some scenarios, will try to upload the crash reports when restarting the app. If the crashes happen too early into the startup process, it can prevent Crashlytics from actually uploading the crash report.

In addition, this will help you avoid having too many crashes.